# I am trying to create an up arrow with text above and below. How can I do that?

Tags: macros, arrows

```
\newcommand*{\underuparrow}[1]{\ensuremath{\underset{\uparrow}{#1}}}
```

This give me a text above the arrow. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you please add an approximate example of how you would use it, with some context?

Answer (score 2):

This is one possibility.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
 \int f(x) dx \mathrel{\substack{\text{Text above}\\\uparrow\\\text{Text below}}} y 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is \mathrel? And yes I think it will work

Comment: `\mathrel` modifies the spacing around something so that it resembles _binary relations_, like the `=` and `\geq`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is second possibility:

```
\def\arrowab{\mathop{\uparrow}\limits}

$$
  \arrowab^x_y, \quad \arrowab^{\rm text~above}_{\rm text~below}
$$

\bye
```

Comment: `$$` ---> `\[`, `{\rm text~above}` ---> `{\mathrm{text~above}}`, ...  ?

Comment: @Zarko No. This makes my answer format dependent. I never do this. Moreover, note that your corrections makes the code less clear and there are more braces `{{}}`.

Comment: really? you have a mes tex and latex macros/commands and use more than 20 year deprecated notation ...  am i wrong?

Comment: Deprecated? It is LaTeX problem, no my problem. The question was no LaTeX oriented, LaTeX was not explicitly mentioned here. Note `\bye` in my code. This means that the code is usable in plain TeX. And if you remove `\bye` and add some more code before and after then it will be (maybe) usable in LaTeX.